# pywinauto: Не понятен вывод метода print_control_identifiers()

Tags: pywinauto

Метод `print_control_identifiers()` возвращает такое (часть вывода):

> Button - 'Закрыть'    (L978, T740, R1030, B762)    |    ['Закрыть',
> 'ЗакрытьButton', 'Button51', 'Закрыть0', 'Закрыть1', 'ЗакрытьButton0',
> 'ЗакрытьButton1']    |    child_window(title="Закрыть",
> control_type="Button")

Вопрос: Что представляет собой эта строка (ниже)?

> ['Закрыть', 'ЗакрытьButton', 'Button51', 'Закрыть0', 'Закрыть1',
> 'ЗакрытьButton0', 'ЗакрытьButton1']

Answer (score 1):

Это возможные best_match имена, которые можно использовать для доступа по атрибуту или ключу. Например:

```
app.MainWindowTitle.dump_tree() # это новое имя метода print_control_identifiers()
app.MainWindow.Button51.draw_outline()
# или эквивалентно
app.MainWindow["Button51"].draw_outline()
# или то же самое
app.MainWindow.child_window(best_match="Button51").draw_outline()
```

Фактически создаётся WindowSpecification (это ещё не найденный реально элемент, а только многоуровневый критерий поиска, аналога локатора в Selenium). best_match означает, что поиск происходит с точностью до опечатки (по некому расстоянию между строками, которое считается с помощью встроенного в питон модуля difflib).